# Generate the DocuSign envelope link for tracking purposes while sending it via email

Tags: javascript, typescript, docusignapi

I am embedding the DocuSign into my application and want to request a signature by email. More information about remote signature implementation can be found here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/

For the email notifications I exclude the clientUserId property. Then DocuSign sends email notifications containing a link for the recipient to access and sign the documents via the DocuSign web interface.

The question is how I can get this remote envelope link to be able to track the envelope status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is using [DocuSign Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/), which is a webhook which can be used to get status updates for envelopes.

This has to be set either account-wide, or per-envelope with event notifications.

You will need to set a listener on your server to get these events, there are code example showing how to do this when you use AWS and Java:

https://github.com/docusign/connect-java-worker-aws

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very helpful. I want to just double-check if I understood you correctly: doest it meant that we can get the envelope id after/while sending it for remote signature?

Comment: yes, you can get the envelope ID as soon as you create an envelope from the DocuSign REST API, that is not related to using the Connect webhook